# Objective C - Passing JSON data from Tableview to another View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

JSON Data:

```
({

    CustDisplayName = "John Doe";
    CustID = 2;
},
    {
    CustDisplayName = "Jane Doe";
    CustID = 21;
})
```

Displaying the data on tableview like a contact list is working and also the segue(Push) from cell to other view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDetailView" sender:indexPath];
}
```

Now I am passing data through prepareForSegue

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushDetailView"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
}
```

The log just shows 0,1,2,3 which is not what I want. I am not sure what is the best way to approach.

1. Select Row get CustID and do another request on another view's viewDidLoad?
2. Select Row get that Array and transfer the string to another view?

I am new to iOS development, I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/fethica/UITableViewJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your destination ViewController's head file, define a property of type NSDictionary named dict. And parse your Json data to an array, which has NSDictionary objects.

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushDetailView"]) {
   UIViewController *controller = segue.destinationviewcontroller;
   controller.dict = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is `indexPath.row` instead of `indexPath`

Comment: This does provide the answer, I believe in the post above the person wanted to print the row selected, which can be obtained using 'indexPath.row' instead of 'indexPath'

Comment: Hi Roger Fan, thanks for raising but Chandan005 is right about this. It actually helps in a certain way. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data source is a `NSArray` filled with `Customer` objects.

First, create a Customer property in your detail viewController:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) Customer customer;
```

Then, you have to set this property when selecting a row. To do that use the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushDetailView"]) {
      DetailViewController*destination= segue.destinationviewcontroller;
      NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
      destination.customer = datasource[indexPath.row];
   }
}
```

Make sure that when you call performSegue you set the cell as the sender.
A way to make sure it is is to create your segue from a storyboard and not perform it manually.

You may also want to use this to easily parse your JSON: https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/